# Getting wrong value from a method

Tags: java, servlets, syntax, casting

Hello I am having a problem with a class
this is the class

```
public class BeerExpert {
public List getBrands(String color){
    List brands = new ArrayList();
    if(color.equals("amber")){
        brands.add("Jack Amber");
        brands.add("Red Moose");
    }
    else {
        brands.add("Jail Pale Ale");
        brands.add("Gout Stout");
    }
    return(brands);
}
```

}

and I am calling this class like this

```
BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
List result = be.getBrands(c);
```

and I get this error Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.List to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List

I don't understand where is the error if the getBrands method returns a List and my result is also List

Comment: Compare the `import` statements of your `List` classes.

Comment: Partially unrelated, but you should use generics unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: The List you return from BeerExpert.getBrands(String color) is of the type java.util.List . The object result is of the type com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List . Either you have used the wrong import statement, or, if you need that kind of List in your class somewhere else, you should use the fully qualified name like so: java.util.List result = be.getBrands(c);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two List classes are different. Check their package names.

Your method `getBrands` returns `java.util.List`, while the other 
class is `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List`. 
So there is nothing unexpected in this exception you get.

Probably you imported the wrong `List` class in your calling code.
In other words, this `List` here:
    `List result = be.getBrands(c);`
is not `java.util.List` as it should be.